# How to open a MacOS target only project in AppCode

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, appcode

I have run

```
 swift package init
```

to create a `Package.swift`

and then - since `Appcode` does not seem to support `Package.swift` I did

```
 swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

to generate a `macos.xcodeproj` .   My `<moduleName>` is `macos`.

When opening the `macos` project in `AppCode` it is still not able to handle it:

[image]

What step is missing /should be changed to open a macOS target project generated via `swift package manager`?

Comment: It seems AppCode opened the project correctly, just compile it once to make SourceKit in-editor warnings go away, like in Xcode.

Comment: I had tried that: the "`Build failed`"  without any specific errors listed.